# Highcharts how to create legends based on the value of points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I know exactly how to enable legend in *Highcharts*, but the problem is how to create legends based on the value of the points from the same series since every legend is used to symbolize a series(a collection of points).

There's is a picture(chart type: *waterfall*) I draw in excel below illustrating what I want, you can see clearly that **orange color legend stands for gaining, while blue one stands for loss, but how do I achieve this in Highcharts?**
[image: example chart]

I've searched a lot but ended with disappointment, please help.

Comment: How to customise the font of legend item and also the legend icon ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is with a dummy series.

Create an extra series, with the name and color that you want, with an empty data array:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Actual Series',
  data: [...data, with points colored as needed...]
}, {
  grouping: false,
  name: 'Dummy Series',
  color: 'chosen color',
  data: []
}]
```

You'll also want to set `grouping` to `false`, so that the dummy series does not take up extra blank space on the plot.

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/vjd3p4s0/

(*also, the same thing using the Waterfall demo:*  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/7vtbzh53/ )

Another way to do this would be to create your own legend, outside of the chart.

Either way, you will lose the functionality of clicking the legend to show/hide the series of for the orange columns. You would have to build a more complex function to edit the data on `legendItemClick` if you that ability is important to you.

Comment: Another question, maybe outside the scope of the question being discussed, is this requirement *mandatory* for any waterfall chart vendor?

Comment: while the answer is acceptable, nevertheless its elegance is doubtful, thank you anyway.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by your question. If you mean, does any other chart library do what you want natively, I am afraid I do not know the answer. In regard to elegance - the more elegant solution is the second one I mentioned - build the legend yourself.

Comment: that's exactly what I was asking, thanks. sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for edited question. You can map your data to two series and set stacking to 'normal'.

```
const data = [10, 20, -10, 20, 10, -10];
const dataPositive = data.map(v => v >= 0 ? v : 0);
const dataNegative = data.map(v => v < 0 ? v : 0);

const options = {
    chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  series: [{
    color: 'blue',
    data: dataPositive,
    stacking: 'normal'
  }, {
    color: 'orange',
    data: dataNegative,
    stacking: 'normal'
  }]
}

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', options);
```

Live example:
https://jsfiddle.net/j2o5bdgs/

[EDIT]

Solution for waterfall chart:

```
const data = [10, 20, -30];
const colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;

const options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'waterfall'
  },
  series: [{
    // Single series simulating 2 series
    data: data.map(v => v < 0 ? {
      y: v,
      color: colors[0]
    } : {
      y: v,
      color: colors[3]
    }),
    stacking: 'normal',
    showInLegend: false
  }, {
    // Positive data serie
    color: colors[3],
    data: [10, 20, 0],
    visible: false,
    stacking: 'normal',
    showInLegend: false
  }, {
    // Negative data serie
    color: colors[0],
    data: [0, 0, -30],
    visible: false,
    stacking: 'normal',
    showInLegend: false
  }, {
    // Empty serie for legend item
    name: 'Series 1',
    color: colors[3],
    stacking: 'normal',
    events: {
      legendItemClick: function(e) {
        const series = this.chart.series;
        const invisibleCount = document.querySelectorAll('.highcharts-legend-item-hidden').length;
        if (this.visible) {
          if (invisibleCount === 1) {
            series[0].hide();
            series[1].hide();
            series[2].hide();
          } else {
            series[0].hide();
            series[2].show();
          }
        } else if (invisibleCount === 2) {
          series[0].hide();
          series[1].show();
        } else {
          series[0].show();
          series[2].hide();
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    // Empty serie for legend item
    name: 'Series 2',
    color: colors[0],
    stacking: 'normal',
    events: {
      legendItemClick: function(e) {
        const series = this.chart.series;
        const invisibleCount = document.querySelectorAll('.highcharts-legend-item-hidden').length;
        if (this.visible) {
          if (invisibleCount === 1) {
            // hide all
            series[0].hide();
            series[1].hide();
            series[2].hide();
            return;
          }
          series[0].hide();
          series[1].show();
        } else {
          if (invisibleCount === 2) {
            series[0].hide();
            series[2].show();
            return;
          }
          series[0].show();
          series[1].hide();
        }
      }
    }
  }]
}

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', options);
```

Live example:
https://jsfiddle.net/2uszoLop/

Comment: It's not rendered properly when I change the chart type to `waterfall` (**target chart type**).

Comment: I've added a solution for waterfall chart